# How to pass a function argument to a created instance inside the function javascript?

Tags: javascript, web3js

I have this async function:

```
async function estimateGas() {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);
  window.contract.methods.buy().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

I want to change the function so that I can choose any of the methods my instance has at will like so:

```
async function estimateGas(argumentName) {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);

  // I want to change here below what was the ".buy()" method with my argument as if it would have been ".argumentName()"

  window.contract.methods.argumentName().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

How can I use the funciton argument to change a method name in an instance created inside the function with javascript?

Comment: Use array syntax with the string of the method name.

Comment: @J.Titus so for instance is the "string" of the method name would be "buy", shell I save it in a varibale with array syntax and then pass it like so:  let argName = ['buy']; and then pass argName[0] ? beacuse i tried that but it does not work. I also tried with the string "buy( )" I also tried with the dot infront.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
async function estimateGas(argumentName) {
  const w3 = await new Web3(window.ethereum);
  window.contract = await new w3.eth.Contract(myContr.abi, myContr.addr);    
  window.contract.methods[argumentName]().estimateGas({from: ethereum.selectedAddress});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

put the function as a parameter then when calling it use parentheses for example:

```html
function main (function){
return function()
}
```